# Sum of digits (upto single digit) of a prime number raised to an even power

Tags: recreational-mathematics, decimal-expansion

I noticed that **sum of digits (upto a single digit) of a prime number** (except 3) **raised to an even power is always either 1, 4 or 7** (3 is an exception. **3 raised to any power always gives the sum of digits upto single digit as 9**).

The primes which have sum of their digits upto single digit as 1 or 8 always give sum of digits upto single digit (when raised to even power) as 1. Those primes which give 4,5 or 7 as the sum of digits upto single digit (when squared) follow this pattern of 4,7,1 (when sum is 7) and 7,4,1 (when sum is 4 or 5) i.e, after every 3rd even power the pattern repeats(given in example below).

Has this been observed before? Is this useful somehow? Can anyone prove or disprove this?

**Examples**

1. PRIMES WITH THEIR SUM OF DIGITS UPTO SINGLE DIGIT AS 1 OR 8

   $19^2 = 361 => 3+6+1 = 10 => 1+0 = 1$

   $19^{24} = 48,98,76,29,30,96,08,46,81,77,16,29,52,77,921 => $ $4+8+9+8+...+9+2+1 = 163 => 1+6+3 = 10 => 1+0=1$

   $233^4 = 2,94,72,95,521 => 2+9+4+7+2+9+5+5+2+1 = 46 => $ $4+6 = 10 => 1+0 = 1$

   $233^{10} = 4,71,58,41,61,16,44,22,54,29,70,449 => $ $4+7+1+5+...+4+4+9 = 100 => 1+0+0 = 1$
2. PRIMES WITH THEIR SUM OF DIGITS UPTO SINGLE DIGIT AS 4 OR 5 OR 7 (Here I am giving only 13 as an example but it works for primes with sum of their digits upto single digit as 5 or 7 as well)

   $13^2 = 169 => 1+6+9 = 16 => 1+6 = 7 = 3+4 <= 34 = $ $8+1+5+...+2+1 <= 815730721 = 13^8$

   $13^4 = 28561 => 2+8+5+6+1 = 22 => 2+2 = 4 = 1+3 <= 13 $ $= 6+7 <= 67 = 1+3+7+...+8+4+9 $ $<= 1,37,85,84,91,849 = 13^{10}$

   $13^6= 4826809 => 4+8+2+6+8+0+9 = 37 => 3+7 = 10 =>$ $ 1+0 = 1 =1+0 <= 10 = 5+5 <= 55 $ $= 2+3+...+1 <=2,32,98,08,51,22,481 = 13^{12}$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) whenever you type a formula on this site. It’s pretty easy. You just enclose your formulae into the $ signs, for the most part. Your post is very hard to read.

Comment: You just reinvented that any squared integer number (not only prime) gives $0$, $1,$ $4$, or $7$ modulo $9$. It is a very well known fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your procedure of calculating a sum of digits of $n$ over and over, until one digit is left, gives just the remainder of dividing $n$ by $9$ (where $0$ is substituted by $9$). This fact follows from a well-known divisibility test: the remainder of a number after dividing by $9$ is equal to the reminder of the sum of its digits. On each step, the result gets smaller, while maintaining its value modulo $9$. So it will become single-digit eventually. All single-digit natural numbers have different remainders modulo $9$.

Now, if we raise an integer to the second power, what remainders modulo $9$ can we get? $$0^2=0,$$ $$1^2=(-1)^2=1,$$ $$2^2=(-2)^2=4,$$ $$3^2=(-3)^2=0,$$ $$4^2=(-4)^2=7.$$

It means that if you take $n^2$ for any integer $n$, not divisible by $3$, then it will give $1$, $4$ or $7$ after your procedure. $3$ raised to any power greater than $1$ will give $9$.

Comment: I also noticed that any prime number cubed only gives 1 or 8 modulo 9 (except 3 obviously). Is this also a known fact?

Comment: @SundararajanV Yes, since $(\pm 2)^3\equiv\mp 1$, $(\pm 4)^3\equiv\pm 1$. I recommend that you consult this wikipedia page for the main [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) principles.

Comment: Thank you. I will check that out